# Adding a right-click Context Menu on a ToolStripMenuItem, without closing the Menu

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, contextmenu, toolstripdropdown

My application has a menu at the top.
The first item in the menu (**File**) has the usual **New**, **Open...**, **Save**, **Save As...** as well as **Open Recent**. This last one is a ToolStripDropDown showing a most-recently-used list of filenames.

I would like to add a right-click Context Menu (not a sub-menu) to the file names which will have one item in the context menu, to remove the right-clicked filename from the list.

I load the file names into the Menu as follows:

```
private void mnuFile_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string fn in mru_files)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem p = new ToolStripMenuItem(fn);
        p.Click += fn_clicked;
        p.MouseDown += fn_MouseDown;
        openRecentToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(p);
    }
}
```

The main portion of this works fine - the `fn_clicked` method is invoked when I click on a file and it will do what it's supposed to do.

In the `MouseDown` Handler I can remove the file from the list as follows:

```
private void fn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem toolStripMenuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;

    if (toolStripMenuItem != null
        && e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right
        && mru_files.Find(x => x == toolStripMenuItem.Text) != null)
    {
        mru_files.Remove(toolStripMenuItem.Text);
    }
}
```

but this doesn't show a menu.

If I add a context menu to the form, and do

```
mnu_ctxMRUitem.Show(xyz, e.X, e.Y);
```

instead of removing the file, I get the Context Menu in the right place, but the original menu with the list of files has disappeared.

How can I show the context menu on right-click of a menu item, without the main menu disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

To force a [ToolStripDropDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown) to remain opened, you can set its [AutoClose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.autoclose) property to `false`.
You can then show a ContextMenuStrip in the location where the right-click was generated.

Subscribe to the `MouseUp` Event of any ToolStripMenuItem that requires a ContextMenuStrip and, if the `e.Button == MouseButtons.Right` test is positive, block the ToolStripDropDown that is the [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.owner) of the ToolStripMenuItem selected.
Use the same `MouseUp` Event Handler for all ToolStripMenuItems.

When the ContextMenuStrip is closed, set the `AutoClose` property back to `true`.

Of course, you need to perform this operation on all ToolStripDropDown components in the hierarchy, since you may want to activate this functionality to sub-items of a ToolStripMenuItem.
This action is performed by the `SetMenutemsAutoClose()` method.

Here, the ToolStripMenuItem that activates the ContextMenuStrip is saved to the `[ContextMenuStrip].Tag` property. Feel free to use any other means to store this reference.

```
private void anyToolStripMenuItem_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
        var menuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
        someContextMenuStrip.Tag = menuItem;
        SetMenutemsAutoClose(menuItem, false);
        someContextMenuStrip.Show(MousePosition);
        someContextMenuStrip.Capture = true;
        menuItem.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(42, SystemColors.MenuHighlight);
    }
}

private async void SomeContextMenuStrip_Closed(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs e)
{
    var cms = sender as ContextMenuStrip;
    if (cms.Tag != null && cms.Tag is ToolStripMenuItem menuItem) {
        // Determine an action based on the ToolStripMenuItem
        Console.WriteLine(menuItem.Name);
        SetMenutemsAutoClose(menuItem, true);
            
        menuItem.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        // Need to somewhat fight against the internal Timer
        await Task.Delay(100);
        if (menuItem.Owner != null) menuItem.Owner.Capture = true;
    }
}

private void SetMenutemsAutoClose(ToolStripMenuItem menu, bool autoClose)
{
    if (menu == null || menu.Owner == null) return;
    while (menu.Owner is ToolStripDropDown dropDown) {
        dropDown.AutoClose = autoClose;
        menu = dropDown.OwnerItem as ToolStripMenuItem;
    }
}
```

<sub>If Pattern Matching is not available in your version of C#, declare the variable in-line, explictly</sub>

Comment: When it shows the Context Menu, the highlight color of the 'someContextMenuStrip' is lost, and therefore it is harder to determine which element was right-clicked.  Is there a way to keep the highlight (or focused) color?

Comment: I've changed the behavior a bit and colorized the currently selected MenuItem. See whether this behavior is good enough, without overriding half of the ContextMenuStrip class or the ToolStripDropDown class.